# List as stream if present or else doesn't update the list?

Tags: java, javafx, collections, mapreduce, java-stream

UPDATE: I fixed my problem with this

```
Optional<Collection<Pair<String, Integer>>> collResult = shufflingResult.stream().filter(c -> c.contains(uniquePair)).findAny();
        if(collResult.isPresent()) {
            collResult.ifPresent(c -> {
                for(int i = 0; i < pFrequencyCount; i++)
                    c.add(uniquePair);
            });
        }
        else {
            Collection<Pair<String, Integer>> newColl = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < pFrequencyCount; i++)
                newColl.add(uniquePair);
            shufflingResult.add(newColl);
        }
```

**But I still wondering why ifPresentOrElse doesn't update the list while just ifPresent do.**

I'm trying to implement a MapReduce similar freamwork, in shuffling phase I'm doing something like it's shown below but when i pass the collection consumer
to ifPresentOrElse method that collection value doesn't get updated in the list

```
public class ExecutingController implements Initializable {

@FXML
Button startBtn;

private List<String> fileLines;
ExecutorService executor;
List<Collection<Pair<String, Integer>>> shufflingResult;

public ExecutingController() {
    fileLines = new ArrayList<>();
    shufflingResult = new ArrayList<>();
    executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
}

private void init() {
    startBtn.setOnAction(e -> {
        fileLines = getInputFileLines();
        try {
            startMappingPhase();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Utils.showFatalError(ex.toString());
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    init();
}

private void startMappingPhase() throws Exception {
    for (String line : fileLines) {
        Future future = new ExecutingController().mapping(line);
        while (!future.isDone()) {
            //
        }
        shuffle((Collection<Pair<String, Integer>>) future.get());
    }
}

private void shuffle(Collection<Pair<String, Integer>> pairs) {
    // Get a unique set of pairs
    Set<Pair<String, Integer>> uniquePairs = new LinkedHashSet<>(pairs);

    // Loop through set
    for (Pair<String, Integer> uniquePair : uniquePairs) {

        // Get a unique pair frequency count
        int pFrequencyCount = Collections.frequency(pairs, uniquePair);

        // Get a stream of result list and check if it's collections has that unique pair if so append it
        // else make a new collection then append it
        shufflingResult.stream().filter(c -> c.contains(uniquePair)).findAny().ifPresentOrElse(new Consumer<Collection<Pair<String, Integer>>>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Collection<Pair<String, Integer>> ps) {
                for (int i = 0; i < pFrequencyCount; i++)
                    ps.add(uniquePair); /* My problem here, I don't get the collection(ps) updated in the list(shufflingResult). */
            }
        }, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Collection<Pair<String, Integer>> newColl = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < pFrequencyCount; i++)
                    newColl.add(uniquePair);
                shufflingResult.add(newColl);
            }
        });

    }
}

private Future<Collection<Pair<String, Integer>>> mapping(String segment) throws Exception {
    Path clsPath = Paths.get(Utils.getAppTempFolder(), "Mapping.class");
    Invoker invoker = new Invoker(clsPath, "Mapping", "mapper");
    return executor.submit(() -> {
        return (Collection<Pair<String, Integer>>) invoker.invoke(segment);
    });
}

private List<String> getInputFileLines() {
    return Utils.getFileLines(Paths.get(Utils.getAppTempFolder(), "input.txt").toFile());
}

}
```

But if i just call ifPresent with lambda collection get updated in the list.

```
shufflingResult.stream().filter(c -> c.contains(uniquePair)).findAny().ifPresent(c -> {
            for(int i = 0; i < pFrequencyCount; i++)
                c.add(uniquePair);
        });
```

My question is why the collection ifPresentOrElse didn't update the collection in the list?

Or is there a similar approach of what i'm trying to do?

[An example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDvIC.png)

Comment: Well, if `shufflingResult` is empty the new collection should be added. However, the current stream wouldn't reflect that and since the pairs are unique you should always add new collections. The second time you call `shuffle()` with the same data the list should already contain appropriate collections unless you clear it in between (btw, why did you define it outside that method?). A question though: Do you realize that `shuffle(pairs)` does not shuffle `pairs` at all?

Comment: I didn't post the whole code, I just do initialize shufflingResult here as example, I call shuffle with pairs that gets mapped by another method so shufflingResult represent final result

Comment: And yeah i know but in MapReduce shuffling phase it's kind of like partitioning

Comment: Well, could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I went out, I will provide it when i'm home, Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Calling `frequency()` repeatedly inside a loop makes this code O(n**2). You should really count all the frequencies at the same time in one pass.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that :) Can you please provide a code of how to do this